# Stretching image to full screen on html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which randomly shows a background image. I sized up the images and lower the bytes to lower the loading speed. However, I want the image to resize with whatever the screen size is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var randnum = Math.random();
    var inum = 3;
    var rand1 = Math.round(randnum * (inum - 1)) + 1;
    images = new Array();
    images[1] = "bgImages/Blue_Venetian_Glass.jpg";
    images[2] = "bgImages/Etched Glass.jpg";
    images[3] = "bgImages/glass.jpg";
    images[4] = "bgImages/Raindrops_on_Glass.jpg";
    var image = images[rand1];
    document.body.style.background = 'url("' + image + '") no-repeat center center fixed';
</script>
```

My question is "what do I need to make the image stretch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best way to achieve that effect would be to use a div with the image inside absolute positioned it that you can style.

HTML to add before `</body>`:

```
<div align="center"><img src="images/BG.jpg" id="bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -5000;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var randnum = Math.random();
var inum = 3;
var rand1 = Math.round(randnum * (inum - 1)) + 1;
images = new Array();
images[1] = "bgImages/Blue_Venetian_Glass.jpg";
images[2] = "bgImages/Etched Glass.jpg";
images[3] = "bgImages/glass.jpg";
images[4] = "bgImages/Raindrops_on_Glass.jpg";
var image = images[rand1];
document.getElementById('bg').src = image;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 `background-size` Property.
Check this link.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools (see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why). You might have linked to a page that contains correct information, but the site has a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to w3schools in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve. (If you use Google Search, and you have a Google account, you can [easily block results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386) from w3schools)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the image a css class and setting the height and width attributes of the class to 100%?